# How to fetch japanese characters in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, internationalization, delphi-7, utf-16

I have a problem with displaying Japanese Character , specifically Unicode character "5c" in my delphi application . I need to save the application names into the registry and then display it in some kind of popup.

I have narrowed down the problem to this code specifically :-

```
  Var
   Str : WideString;
   Str2: WideString;
   Str3 : WideString; 
 TntEdit5.Text := TntOpenDialog1.FileName; //correctly displayed

 Str3 := TntEdit5.Text;

 ShowMessage('Original =' + Str3);

 Str := UTF8Encode(TntEdit5.Text) ;
 ShowMessage('UTF8Encode =' + Str3);


 Str2 := UTF8Decode(Str) ;
 ShowMessage('UTF8Decode =' + Str3);
 end;
```

I dont get the correct name in Str, Str2 and Str3 . So how to fetch the name in a string ?
I dont want to display the text but i want to use it to save to registry and other functions.

Instead of SHowMessage, I used `MessageBoxW(Form1.Handle, PWChar(   Str3 ), 'Path', MB_OK   );` which gave me correct result.

But I want to use this string internally, like write the string into a file etc. How to do that ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: http://objectmix.com/delphi/401792-does-d7-support-japanese-chinese.html

Comment: BTW, why not use UTF8-capable CodeTyphon instead of obsolete D7 ?

Comment: Well, you work with widestrings like `Str3 := Str + Str2`. That *IS* work with strings. Or ask more specific questions. For example for the saving them to registry i already gave you 4 options in the answer, and for ShowMessages to. There just ain't a thing called "just work" and that cannot be answered.

Comment: @Super_User if you no more use ShowMessage - remove it from the code, it is plainly misleading. And fix or remove usage of `UTF8**code` functions.

Comment: "Writing string to file" is very different depending on file type and internal structure. Is the file a database of Firebird SQL server ? or an e-mail file ? or ini-file? or what ?

Comment: Additionally look http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JclWideStrings.pas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `Str` does not match the type of result of `UTF8Encode` - so the line `Str := UTF8Encode` damages data. Instead of `Str` you should declare and use variable with a datatype mathcing the one of `Utf8Encode` result.

Same is true for `Str2 := UTF8Decode(Str)` line with regard to wrong data type of `Str` parameter the. It should be replaced with another var of proper datatype.

`Str3` is not declared, so the code won't even compile. Add the `Str3: WideString;` line.

---

`ShowMessage` does not work with UTF-16, so then you make your own popup function that does.

Make your own dialog containing `Tnt` unicode-aware Label to display the text. And your new `ShowMessage`-like function would set the label's caption and then display that dialog instead of stock unicode-unaware one.

*You may look at http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP%2CVista%2CSeven for exampel of such dialogs, but i don't know if they are UTF-16 aware on D7.*

Another option is searching TnT Sources for a ready-made unicode-aware function like ShowMessage - there may be one, or not.

Yet another option is using Win32 API directly, namely the `MessageBoxW` function working with `PWideChar` variables for texts: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx

*@DavidHeffernan `MessageBoxW` needs a lot of boilerplate both due to using C-Strings and for giving too much flexibility. It may be considered kinda good replacement for `MessageDlg` but not so much for `ShowMessage`. Then i am sure that TnT has `ShowMessage` conversion and that implementing own dialog would be good for both application look-and-feel and topic-starter experience.*

*You may also switch from obsolete Delphi 7 to modern CodeTyphon that uses UTF-8 for strings out of the box. You should at very least give it a try.*

---

To read and write `WideString` from registry using Delphi 7 RTL you can make two easy options:

1. Convert WideString to UTF8 AnsiString and save it via `TRegistry.WriteString` and do back conversion on reading.
2. Save `WideString` as binary data: `Cardinal(Length)` followed by `array of WideChar` using `TRegistry.WriteBinaryData`
3. You can also use `function RegReadWideString(const RootKey: DelphiHKEY; const Key, Name: string): WideString;` and `RegWriteWideString` courtesy of http://jcl.sf.net

Whatever approach you'd choose - you have to do your own class on top of TRegistry that would be uniformly implementing those new `TYourNewRegistry.WriteWideString` and `TYourNewRegistry.ReadWideString` methods, so that the string written would always be read back using the same method.

*However, since you already got TNT installed - then look carefully inside,. there just should be ready-made unicode-aware class like `TTntRegistry` or something like that.*

Comment: I have added the declaration of Str3 . and I have also updated my question. I dont want to just display the text. I want to work with the string further